# HTML changing images with JS interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I have a code and I need to do simple action: I have 28 images in my div and I need to change it every 41ms.

I have the HTML:

```
<div class="full_slider">
<img id="bgs_49" style="visibility: visible; display: block; opacity: 1;" src="images/background/10_00049.jpg" class="full_slider_child" alt="bg" />
<img id="bgs_50" src="images/background/10_00050.jpg" class="full_slider_child" alt="bg" />
<img id="bgs_51" src="images/background/10_00051.jpg" class="full_slider_child" alt="bg" />
<img id="bgs_52" src="images/background/10_00052.jpg" class="full_slider_child" alt="bg" />
<img id="bgs_53" src="images/background/10_00053.jpg" class="full_slider_child" alt="bg" />
<img id="bgs_54" src="images/background/10_00054.jpg" class="full_slider_child" alt="bg" />
<img id="bgs_55" src="images/background/10_00055.jpg" class="full_slider_child" alt="bg" />
<img id="bgs_56" src="images/background/10_00056.jpg" class="full_slider_child" alt="bg" />
<img id="bgs_57" src="images/background/10_00057.jpg" class="full_slider_child" alt="bg" />
<img id="bgs_58" src="images/background/10_00058.jpg" class="full_slider_child" alt="bg" />
<img id="bgs_59" src="images/background/10_00059.jpg" class="full_slider_child" alt="bg" />
<img id="bgs_60" src="images/background/10_00060.jpg" class="full_slider_child" alt="bg" />
<img id="bgs_61" src="images/background/10_00061.jpg" class="full_slider_child" alt="bg" />
<img id="bgs_62" src="images/background/10_00062.jpg" class="full_slider_child" alt="bg" />
```

and I have the JS:

```
var bgs = ['49', '50', '51', '52', '53', '54', '55', '56', '57', '58', '59', '60', '61', '62', '61', '60', '59', '58', '57', '56', '55', '54', '53', '52', '51', '50', '49']
var pos = 1;


setInterval(function() {
pos = (pos+1) % bgs.length;
pos_early = (pos-1) % bgs.length;

slider_next = $("#bgs_" + pos);
slider_prev = $("#bgs_" + pos_early);

slider_prev.css({
   'visibility' : 'hidden',
   'display'    : 'none',
   'opacity'    : 0 
});

slider_next.css({
   'visibility' : 'visible',
   'display'    : 'block',
   'opacity'    : 1 
});
}, 41);
```

what I need to do, that every 41ms previuos image should get visibility: none, display: none, opacity: 0, and the next image should get visibility: visible, display: block and opacity: 1. How I should do it?

BTW: my code is not working

Comment: You have duplicate IDs. That is not going to work.

Comment: i fixed that, but thats not helped me

Comment: every 41 ms? how big are these images? are you sure the browser is capable of rendering a new image every 41ms? are all these images preloaded? Have you tried your code with a much longer delay?

Comment: It would be more maintainable by toggling a class. That way your css will be constrained to a stylesheet.

Comment: Well, your image ids start with bgs_49. Your `pos` is starting at 1.

Comment: yes, images is preloaded, i tried with longer delay. This is not the problem. I think my JS have a bad logic. And pos is starting on 1, it have no matter when it starst. Now it starts at bgs_50, change bgs_49 style to not visible and setting bgs_50 style to visible, but thats not working

Comment: `slider_next = $("#bgs_" + pos);` results in trying to select `slider_next = $("#bgs_2");` on the first time. You don't have an image with that id. But just go with the answer below, that seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
var cntMax = $('.full_slider').find('img').length;
var cnt = 0;
setInterval(function(){
   $('.full_slider img:eq('+cnt+')').show().siblings().hide();
   cnt==cntMax? cnt=0:cnt++;
},41);
```

Comment: that helped me a alot, thanks. But i still have a problem with mozilla. With chrome 28fps have no lag, but with mozilla I can feel laggy there., any suggestions?

Comment: @baitas212123 it would be to increase the ms, i'm not sure if there is any other way than that

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment above an alternative would be to toggle a class so that you keep all of your css in your stylesheets so that you have a **separation of concerns**.

**JS**

```
setInterval(function () {
    $(".full_slider img").eq(0).removeClass('show').next('img').addClass('show').end().appendTo(".full_slider");
}, 41);
```

**CSS**

```
.full_slider_child.show {
    visibility: visible; 
    display: block; 
    opacity: 1;
}
```